# Discord Bot - Unknown emoji when encoded in UTF8

Tags: utf-8, discord.js, emoji, ansi

when I encode my file in UTF8 I can't use the emoji anymore.

```js
    if (_local.temp.pycx !== undefined) {
      _local.temp.pycx.reactions.find(x.emoji === "ðŸ").remove(user);
    };

      if (_local.lobby.players.length === 3) {
        _local.temp.pycx = await channel.send("React to this message to start the game. [Everyone must vote to start]");
        _local.temp.pycx.react("ðŸ");

        addReactable(_local.temp.pycx, actions.startGame, "ðŸ");

      };
```

This code works like a charm if the file is in ANSI. But I need UTF8...

I tried to put  but it doesn't work... `Unknown Emoji`

What can I do to make it work with UTF8 encode?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad I didn't see there was more weird emoji bellow. It works fine with the unicode emoji.